# Extra item being added in localStorage?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to build message component in react. Currently I just saving entered messages in localStorage but whenever I am pushing a message 2 rows get pushed in localStorage which should not happen. I have checked it but not able to get why this happening.

**message comp**

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

interface IMessage {
  user: string;
  text: string;
}

export const Message = () => {
  const [messages, setMessages] = useState<IMessage[]>([]);
  const [message, setMessage] = useState("");
  const [user, setUser] = useState("testuser");

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchedMessages = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("messages") as any);
    if (fetchedMessages) {
      console.log("fetchedMessages=>", fetchedMessages);
    }
  }, [messages]);

  const handleFormSubmit = (event: any) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    setMessages((messages) => {
      const newData = [...messages, { text: message, user: user }];
      let oldStorage =
        JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("messages") as any) || [];
      const oldStorageN = [...oldStorage, { text: message, user: user }];
      localStorage.removeItem("messages");
      localStorage.setItem("messages", JSON.stringify(oldStorageN));
      return newData;
    });
    setMessage("");
  };

  return (
    <>
      <div className="MessageContainer">
        {messages.map((message) => {
          return (
            <div key={message.text + message.user}>
              <div>
                <strong>{message.user}</strong>
                <div>{message.text}</div>
              </div>
            </div>
          );
        })}
      </div>
      <div>
        <form onSubmit={handleFormSubmit}>
          <div>
            <input
              type="text"
              name="message"
              onChange={(e) => {
                setMessage(e.target.value);
              }}
              value={message}
            />
          </div>
          <div>
            <input type="submit" value="send" />
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};
```

This is code link

https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-starter-typescript-qowlvq?file=components/Message.tsx

**Note:** on StackBlitz it's working fine, but on my machine it's adding two entries per message.

Comment: Did you try ctrl+F5 ?

Comment: Yeah, try @Zunayed's method. Sometimes, the page needs to be reloaded in order to commit the changes done by the application to the localStorage